# String comparison in C gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-14.04

I'm teaching someone C programming with simple exercises.
I'm unable to get the `strcmp()` function to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 20
int main()
{
  char s1[MAX], s2[MAX];
  printf("Enter s1: ");
  scanf("%s",s1);
  printf("Enter s2: ");
  scanf("%s",s2);
  printf("S1 is %s\n",s1);
  printf("S2 is %s\n",s2);
  // string concatenation
  strcat(s1,s2);
  printf("S1 is %s\n",s1);
  // string copy
  strcpy(s1,s2);
  printf("S1 is %s\n",s1);
  // find the length of the string
  int a = strlen(s1);
  printf ("Length of S1 is %d\n", a);
  int b = strlen(s2);
  printf ("Length of S2 is %d\n", b);
  // string comparison               <<----- This is where it does not work
  int c;
  c = strcmp(s1, s2);
  printf("C is %d\n",c);
  if (c==0)
    printf("S1 = S2\n");
  else if (c<0)
    printf("S1<S2\n");
  else 
    printf("S1>S2\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles (with warnings) but does not execute. It throws `segmentation fault` error and quits.
I used the pointer style syntax too, but it gets me errors during compile.

As a side note, I saw lot of websites using `gets()` `puts()`. But when used in my programs it tells me that the use of the above functions are deprecated. How to determine which functions can be used and where to look for them?

**EDIT**
Program output:

```
prasannarajaram@ubuntu:~/Documents/programs/C$ ./string
Enter s1: test
Enter s2: case
S1 is test
S2 is case
S1 is testcase
S1 is case
Length of S1 is 4
Length of S2 is 4
C is 0
S1 = S2
```

This is where I started adding `*` pointer symbols to try to see what would work.

Comment: Segment fault is not awakened in the shown example code & input.

Comment: See my explanation on why your strcmp always return 0.

Comment: Fix the warnings — the compiler is trying to tell you that you've got mistakes in your code. (You removed the `&` from `&s1` in the call to `scanf()`. The code I see doesn't generate warnings for me with that change.)  What does crash is the `strcat()` operation when the names I type are long enough (I used `abracadabra` and `'persephone`, for 11 + 10, which are too long to fit in `s1`).  You should make sure there's enough space before concatenating strings.  You should check that `scanf()` worked, and limit the input with `if (scanf("%19s", s1) != 1) { …process error…; }`, etc.

Comment: so... you fixed the code and it works now?

Comment: I tested here and it's working now, he just didn't mark anything as the answer, just edited his question, even for the right ones.

Comment: @AlessandroCaetano, I was away from my PC. Just accepted your answer. Thanks for pointing out the logical mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the pointers on lines:

```
printf("S1 is %s\n",*s1);
printf("S2 is %s\n",*s2);
```

To be like this:

```
printf("S1 is %s\n",s1);
printf("S2 is %s\n",s2);
```

To know more about pointers in c, there are a lot of tutorials on the internet, like this one: http://karwin.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/c-pointers-explained-really.html

To know more about c and c++ functions you can relate to their official documentation, here on this link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/

**EDIT:**
On this line, you're making a strcat:

```
strcat(s1,s2)
```

So s1 will have the value of s1+s2, but on the next line you're making a copy of s2 into s1.

```
strcpy(s1,s2)
```

After that, s1 will have the same value as s2, so s1 is now equals s2. That's why your strcmp is always returning 0. You can see that happening on your output.

```
S1 is test      #S1 initialy
S2 is case      #S2 initialy
S1 is testcase  #S1 after strcat(s1,s2)
S1 is case      #S1 after strcpy(s1,s2)
```

**As you can see S1 have the same value as S2 in the end.**

This should work :)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `scanf` incorrectly. I suspect your program's state is being corrupted by the call to `scanf` but it isn't being discovered until you call `strcmp`.

When using `scanf` to read standard-input into a string, use this format:

```
#define LENGTH 20
char str[LENGTH+1] = {0};
scanf("%20s", str); // note the "max-length" format parameter of 20.
```

By using the address-of operator (`&`) it means `scanf` will write to the address defined by the **value** passed-in, as you don't set an initial value for your `s1` value your program's behaviour is undefined.

To be safer, consider using the `LENGTH` define'd value in the format-string, so the value of `20` isn't repeated:

```
scanf("%" #LENGTH "s", str)
```

Comment: `#define LENGTH 20;` --> `#define LENGTH 20`, `char str[LENGTH];` --> `char str[LENGTH+1];`, `scanf("%" #LENGTH "s")` is bad.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks - I fixed the first 2 issues (and zeroed-out the `str` array), but what is wrong with my usage of `scanf`?

Answer (score 1):

`scanf`'s second argument is supposed to have an address, which is `s1` and `s2`. Change it to:

```
scanf("%s", s1);
scanf("%s", s2);
```

Comment: why should we skip the `&` symbol in this `scanf`?

Comment: @Prasanna For a normal `int x;`, `&x` is its address. For an array `char s[MAXN];`, `s` itself is the starting address of the string.